# Exported variables inside ssh session are empty

Tags: shell, ssh, quoting, variable

I am trying to export a variable inside a ssh session and reference the variable in the next write command.

```
sshpass -p "password" ssh -t -t my-box <<EOF
  export newUrl="this is a url"
  sudo -E sh -c 'echo "url=$newUrl" >> /path/to/file'
  exit
EOF
```

Instead of printing,

```
url=this is a url
```

to the file, it just prints,

```
url=
```

Why the variable's value is not accessible in the same ssh session?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the here-document is indicated by `<<EOF` (without any quotes), the content of the here-document is subject to expansion of `` \$` ``. Hence `$newUrl` in the here document expands to its value in the local shell.

To instead pass `$newUrl` to the remote shell and have it expand the variable, you can protect the `$` from expansion: `\$newUrl` instead of `$newUrl`, or use a literal here-document: `<<'EOF'` instead of ``<

You're expanding the variable `newUrl` in a string which is going to be interpreted by a shell. This means that the value of the variable will be interpreted as a shell script fragment, not as a string. If the value contains shell special characters, havoc will ensue. (Which characters are problematic depends on which works-in-the-nominal-case solution you use.)

Instead of using many layers of quoting and expansion, pass the URL as input to the command running as root. Then you have nothing to worry about. This has the added advantage of working even if sudo is not configured to accept `-E`, which is fairly common. You can use `sudo sh -c 'cat >>/path/to/file'`, or better, to avoid any potential quoting issues on the file, `sudo tee -a /path/to/file`.

```
sshpass -p "password" ssh -t -t my-box <<'EOF'
  newUrl="this is a url"
  printf '%s\n' "$newUrl" | sudo tee -a /path/to/file
EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to export with sudo. The variable gets lost when you sudo to another user. You can as well set `Defaults env_keep += "newUrl"` in your sudoers file in etc.

Comment: That's not the problem since Madhavan is using `sudo -E`. This would either work as intended or trigger an error.